# I want to create View from the system tables

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

I wanted to create a view from the system tables, I could output the syntax which I want to run but how could I run that output command?
I created the following query which output the syntax to create the table

```
SELECT

'CREATE VIEW [Uti_John].[Vw_' + x.table_name +']' +
' AS SELECT * FROM [' + x.schema_name + '].[' + x.table_name +']' 
FROM
(
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name  
       ,name AS table_name   
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE name like 'T%' 
and SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'dbo'
) x
```

### Output

```
CREATE VIEW [Uti_John].[Vw_TNAME] AS SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TNAME]
CREATE VIEW [Uti_John].[Vw_TClient] AS SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TClient]
CREATE VIEW [Uti_John].[Vw_TClaim] AS SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TTClaim]
CREATE VIEW [Uti_John].[Vw_TInsurance] AS SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TTInsurance]
CREATE VIEW [Uti_John].[Vw_Ttest] AS SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Ttest]
```

copying manually one by one output of this creates the view but how could I run this output in a loop and create automatically?

Comment: You have no choice but to output those into a temp table and then use while loop to execute it one by one. You can't have multiple `CREATE VIEW` within the same batch

Comment: Use a cursor and dynamic SQL.

Comment: cursor is not getting supported in synapse

Comment: i have used the following code, it worked printing the first view but it goes in loop and  issue is the first view is already created. I am not sure how to add the conditionif not exisits then do this condition

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sys.views` view to check if the view already exists.

```
DECLARE  @SQL NVARCHAR(max)='*';

WHILE @SQL IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 

    SET @SQL = NULL;

    SELECT @SQL = 
    'CREATE VIEW [Uti_John].[Vw_' + x.table_name +']' +
    ' AS SELECT * FROM [' + x.schema_name + '].[' + x.table_name +']' 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name  
               ,t.name AS table_name   
        FROM sys.tables t
        WHERE t.name like 't%' 
        and SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) = 'dbo'
        AND NOT EXISTS (    SELECT * 
                            FROM sys.views v 
                            WHERE v.name = 'Vw_' + t.name 
                            AND OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(v.object_id) = 'Uti_John'
                        )
    ) x

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

    PRINT @SQL;

END ;
```